# Dropbox Datastore - Sharing data across user accounts

Tags: dropbox-api

Is it possible to share data saved by an app across all user accounts that have the application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a supported operation; the datastore API is really meant as a synced substitute for local storage, not as a way to access a single shared database.

**UPDATE:** Datastore sharing is now supported (see other answer). But the intended sharing model is more that you share a specific datastore with some of your friends/colleagues/etc., not across all accounts -- the latter is possible but it may not scale to millions of users.

Comment: Is the datastore saved in a folder visible to the user in Dropbox, and if so could users share the folder?

Comment: No, the datastore is not visible in the Dropbox folder. (Keeping it up to date and dealing with direct edits to the file would defeat much of the purpose of using datastores.) We are working on a more direct solution for sharing datastores, stay tuned.

Comment: Any news on the shared datastores?

Comment: We're working on it... But we're going to release another exciting feature first.

Comment: I am also interested in being able to share and sync datastores between users. The inability to do so seems to me to be a major downside of opting to use datastores vs standard files (which can be sync'd and shared by multiple users)

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2014, there are shared Datastores in the Dropbox Datastore API https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/

The blog post with the release news is here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/107/new-datastore-features-shared-datastores-local-datastores-and-datastore-webhooks